# Can you revive turnips?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I time warp a LOT. Lately I've been very invested in the stock market and I've spent about 10 million bells on turnips. Today I accidentally set the clock a day backwards, and all of my turnips became rotten.

This isn't the first time this has happened to me. I'm sick of losing tons of money because of my carelessness.

When I set the clock forward again, the turnips are still spoiled.

**Is there a way to reverse the spoilage of turnips?**

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment above, the point in the turnips rotting is to prevent time warping.

As many people have tried to find a solution for un-spoiling turnips, none have found one yet.

Here are some links where people have asked the same question:

**GameFAQS**

[Help! Spoiled Turnips.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/2000455-animal-crossing-new-leaf-online-trade/66926703)

[Time travel and Spoiled Turnips?](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997811-animal-crossing-new-leaf/answers/370392-time-travel-amp-spoiled-turnips)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to unspoil your turnips.

When playing with the Turnip Market and Time travel, the best strategy is to keep changing your clock one day forward. This way, your turnips will never spoil and you can potentially generate millions of bells!

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is before you buy the turnips time travel to see what price they are each day of the week, then come back to the Sunday and buy the turnips, wait till the day they are most exspensive and sell.